# django modified_at field with database level auto update

Tags: django, postgresql, triggers

I need to have modifed_at fields in my Django project. A field that updates every time a row updates in the database, despite where the update comes from: through calling `.save()` or through `queryset.update()` or even when updates happen in the database directly and not from the Django app.

there is an `auto_now` property that does not solve my problem according to [this SO question(based on Django document)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59332214/django-update-modified-at-when-doing-update).
other SO questions(like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159958/auto-now-field-is-not-updating-with-updating-using-filter) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766018/how-to-create-a-datetimefiled-that-keeps-the-last-edited-time-in-django)) ask the same thing, update instance at every change not only `.save()`

This problem can be solved using triggers as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035980/update-timestamp-when-row-is-updated-in-postgresql) but this way we need to write the same trigger for every modifed_at field in models.

as discussed in [this Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15566) this problem will not be addressed and solved in Django. even [the suggested patch](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1872523#L83) only updates the instance if it changes via Django.

the only way that comes to my mind is to do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924619/setting-database-level-defaults-for-fields-in-django) in a mixin. a mixin that when inherited creates a trigger for fields with auto_now=True. maybe change SQL when Django creates the model creation SQL. but I don't know how to implement this.

so I have two questions:

1. what is the best way to achieve database-level updates for modified_at fields
2. If my suggested way is the best option how to implement it?

I would like to have a database-agnostic solution but FYI currently I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Have you considered using a `post_save` signal?

Comment: @Lewis `post_save` does not do the trick as documented: Finally, realize that update() does an update at the SQL level and, thus, does not call any save() methods on your models, nor does it emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling Model.save()). If you want to update a bunch of records for a model that has a custom save() method, loop over them and call save()
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#update

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if you use triggers you'd have to create a trigger for every table.

To make this easier however you could create a migration file to create/destroy the trigger. Here's an [example](https://objectpartners.com/2019/01/24/creating-raw-sql-migrations-in-django/).

Then it would just be a matter of copy-pasting that migration file whenever you create a new model.

**Edit**:

You could even override the `makemigrations` command to automatically add the creation of the trigger step to the operations of the initial migrations file. Here's an answer that shows [how to override management commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62189966/django-makemigrations-override-to-create-migration-files-with-custom-names).

Answer (score -2):

So you can use the Django's `auto_now` field for that.
If you want to auto populate the DateTimeField when creating a new object you can do this: `created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name=_("created_at"))`

If you want to update the field anytime the object is updated you can do this instead: `updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name=_("updated at"))`

For more info you can refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

Comment: As I said in the question `auto_now` does not update when using `queryset.update` or when updating directly from the database not via Django.